# Double increment on an integer variable, does it work as intended?

Tags: c++

I have some code with lines which increment a counter.

```
++ count;
```

Sometimes I have an if condition which means I should increment count by 2.

```
count += 2;
```

Does "double increment'ing" work in the same way?

```
++ ++ count;
```

It would be helpful to know if both C and C++ compilers interpret this the same way.

Comment: I don't believe it's required by the standard, for the same reasons as found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points). However, I'm not certain enough of that to do any more than leave a comment.

Comment: @AchmadJP: Trying something that may lead to UB is an entirely worthless endeavor. It may appear to work, while it doesn't.

Comment: I don't know, but it's very ugly.

Comment: What is more readable: `++ ++ count;` or `count += 2;`.

Comment: @R_Kapp: It is well defined: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p4 . But is horrible style.

Comment: I personally think `++ ++ count` is more readable, when working with only `++ count` and `++ ++ count`

Comment: ... probably a lot of people disagree with me. Perhaps `count += 1` and `count += 2` is more, more readable, if you "get me"

Comment: @user3728501: You might change your mind if you have to fix code which includes this and similar constructs. I'd refuse such code as hard to maintain and so would some friends of mine. But feel free to use it, until I have to review your code :-)

Comment: To paraphrase Chris Rock; just because you can do something don't mean it's to be _done_.

Comment: You should really stick to one language.

Comment: I find it bizarre that people don't like this. What's the point of `++` if you can't stick'em together to make your code look nice?

Comment: Do not add tags for unrelated langauges. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @user3728501 So, in that case, what's the point of having to write `count += 10`, when we can write `++++++++++++++++++++count`? It looks _so_ nice. It would be way nicer if we rewrite `count += 20` in that form!

Comment: @Olaf Surely applies to both C and C++?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Of course that would be silly. Like I said in my question, I only ever require increment by 1 or 2.

Comment: @user3728501: how about first trying yourself before posting?

Comment: @Olaf Sorry what? Well obviously I did try, I wanted to know if it was legal or not and why

Comment: @user3728501: "Surely applies to both C and C++?" - If you had tried, you would not have stated that.

Comment: I tried a c++ compiler

Comment: @olaf does it matter that much? why not choose not to answer the question of it bothers you so much

Comment: @user3728501: Because you got it wrong. (btw. I did not answer). Re-read my comments then think again.

Answer (score 7):

As this is clearly syntactically correct, the question that remains is: *"Is this UB because of [unsequenced writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)?"*

It is not (in C++11 and later) because

> 5) The side effect of the built-in pre-increment and pre-decrement operators is sequenced before its value computation (implicit rule due to definition as compound assignment)

(From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order))

So the code is fine as of C++11.

However, the sequencing rules were different before that, and pre-C++11, the code actually has UB.

In C, that code does not even compile.

The fact that the behavior is different between C and C++ and even between different C++ standards and that this question arises in the first place is a hint that the simple `count += 2;` is the safer and more readable version. You should prefer it over the "cute and clever" `++ ++count;`.

Comment: I think it was UB before C++11.

Comment: See [intro.execution](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#15) for the standard reference

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, added. I learned C++ after C++11 was published, so I tend to miss such things.

Comment: Lucky you! I can't even use the stuff at the moment.

Comment: @Olaf Well, `++++i` just doesn't compile in C, so that makes it easy right?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods. One that obviously works, one where you have to ask a question on StackOverflow. There are comments saying "in C++ 11 or later"... How sure are you that your C++ code runs with C++ 11 and not something older? Even if you use extensions that were not part of an earlier language, your language could be C++0x with some extensions.

Clearly you shouldn't care whether the second method works or not, but use the one that obviously works.

Comment: Compatibility with an older version of the standard cannot be a reason not to use a feature. Otherwise no new features would be used. But you have other valid points.

Comment: @Olaf The thing is, there is UB, which the compiler will most likely not warn you about. With most other features, you get either a compiler error, or well defined behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I still wounder why this is allowed anyway. Which lvalue does the "outer" `++` increment as side-effect?

Comment: @Olaf I guess the same as the inner one? Pre-increment yields an lvalue (at least in C++)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Ok, so there is another difference. It does not in C. So, that intermediate lvalue is incremented then and just dropped, I suppose? Makes the construct look even more obscure to me. Anyway, thanks for the infos.